# R: data.table Subsetting multiple data sets at the same time

Tags: r, data.table

I am currently using data.table in R and am attempting to subset a list of several data tables down to one specific variable called "name". I have tried using lapply to do so, but haven't been successful. Is there something wrong with my code?

Here's what I've tried:

```
   data_tables<-c("one", "two", "three", "four", "five")
   lapply(mget(data_tables),function(x)x[, c("name")])
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `.(`

```
library(data.table)
lapply(mget(data_tables),function(x)x[, .(name)])
```

Or specify the column/columns in `.SDcols` and subset the `.SD`

```
lapply(mget(data_tables),function(x)x[, .SD, .SDcols = 'name'])
```

Or if we want to extract as a vector, use `[[`

```
lapply(mget(data_tables),function(x) x[["name"]])
```